# "incorporated into bacteria"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "*incorporated into bacteria*" here mean "*inserted into bacteria*" or "*grown in the form of bacteria*"?

From the works of [Eduardo Kac](http://www.ekac.org/geninfo2.html)):

> The key element of the work is an "artist's gene", a synthetic gene that was created by Kac by translating a sentence from the biblical book of Genesis into Morse Code, and converting the Morse Code into DNA base pairs according to a conversion principle specially developed by the artist for this work. **The Genesis gene was incorporated into bacteria**, which were shown in the gallery. Participants on the Web could turn on an ultraviolet light in the gallery, causing real, biological mutations in the bacteria.

Comment: I would take it to mean "inserted".

Comment: Yes, because of the way [gene splicing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_engineering) works, it means "inserted", becoming part of the living bacteria. Of course, when the back yetis reproduce, the new gene will be copied, and live on in the next generation. Interesting use of the fact he majority of DNA is ignored by the organism (aka is "junk"). So you can put basically  anything you want in there, and it'll be OK.

Comment: @DanBron - "Back yetis"?  (Your spelling is abominable. ;) )

Comment: @HotLicks If my spelling disgusts you, just be happy you've never had to watch back yetis reproduce.

Comment: @DanBron - I was trying to picture that.  But I suppose we should try to keep things PG.

Comment: Tasty *morsels* for the bacteriophage?